# How to use css3 transitions to animate 3x3 LI items on page load?

Tags: html, css

My page has a `<UL>` with 9 `<LI>s` that render in a 3x3 grid. I would like to know a way to animate these items on page load, So they build 1 at a time, flying in from the center of the grid.

Does anyone know of any tutorials or examples along the idea above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to accomplish this. One, using CSS3 transitions, in which you need to apply some kind of trigger (like adding a classname via javascript).

Here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VnrcJ/

The other way is CSS3 animations, which is pure CSS (requires no javascript trigger) but is *a lot* more CSS as each `li` needs it's own animation *(especially when supporting multiple browser & their prefixes)*.

Here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zT7jS/

***Obviously, you will want to use all browser prefix combinations, I've only used `-webkit-` in the fiddles***